# Can a Windows batch file call another program without waiting for that program to finish?

Tags: batch

I'm using Windows 7, and have a simple batch file to copy portable executables off my thumb drive to %TEMP%, and then start them.  The goal is to prevent Windows from holding my thumbdrive hostage until I kill all the programs I started up from it.

However the control flow does not continue to the next app unless I kill the first one, which obviously doesn't work for this purpose.

In a Unix shell script I'd simply add `&` after the executable I start up, but I can't find an equivalent for batch files.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `start` command.

Like so:
  `start someprogram.exe`

It will start the program then give control back to the main batch file, running the second program in the background.

Comment: Excellent: thanks.  I'm sure that was a painfully dumb question to anyone who regularly works with batch files.

Comment: If the path for the executable contains spaces, you need to use `start "" "foo\my program.exe"`.  Type `start /?` for details.

Comment: Not dumb at all, it's a good question. You can also run batch files from other batch files using the call command. On StackOverflow.com there's a question with a list of cool tricks you can do on the Windows command line, it's great!